# NSDateFormetter losing an year

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I was using `NSDateFormatter` to convert a date `NSString` instance to a `NSDate` object. At a point, I realized that something isn't right, when I did a check, it seemed like `NSDateFormatter` was loosing a whole year when converting from a string to a `NSDate`.

The code looks like this:

```
NSString *dateString = [dictionary objectForKey:@"match_date_time"];
if (dateString) {
     // dateString is "2012-10-30 04:30:00"

     NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
     [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

     self.date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
     // self.date ends up 2011-10-30 04:30:00 +0000, yes 2011 not 2012.
}
```

Does anyone know why does `NSDateFormatter` fails so miserably?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write below code

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. I used the wrong symbol for year. http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Comment: if my ans helpfull to you so u can upward it.

Comment: It takes 8 minutes to be able to accept the right answer. Thanks.